# using cv::rectangle, cv::circle, cv::line directly in GpuMat?

Tags: opencv

I am wondering if there is any way to draw a ROI using `cv::rectangle`, `cv::circle`, `cv::line` on a `cv::cuda::GpuMat`? Currently, I was working on a `OpenCV` project and I want to use those OpenCV CUDA APIs to improve the performance of the algorithm. But I find that there'are not OpenCV CUDA APIs for those drawing functions like rectangle, circle, and line. So my question is that is there a solution for this issue? Maybe OpenGL? Because these drawing functions are usually the bottleneck of the algorithm if we want to visualize the result of the output.